# Why didn't mutate fill all rows? Was using mutate and ifelse to look up imputed values from another dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, plyr

Here is the deal. Was trying to use `mutate` from the `plyr` package to look up an appropriate value from another dataframe, if, the `v` variable in the original dataframe was `NA`. The looked up value is supposed to go into a new variable `imputed`. I also defined a custom function for this look up purpose.

Here is the code:

```
if(!require(plyr)){
  install.packages("plyr")
  library(plyr)
}
df = data.frame(d=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                g=rep(c(1,2,3),3),
                v=c(5,NA,NA,5,NA,NA,5,NA,NA))
imputed = data.frame(g=c(1,2,3),
                     v=c(5,10,15))
getImputed = function(p){
  imputed[imputed$g==p,"v"]
}
df = mutate(df,imputed=ifelse(is.na(v),getImputed(g),v))
df
```

And this is the resulting dataframe:

```
  d g  v imputed
1 1 1  5       5
2 1 2 NA      10
3 1 3 NA      15
4 2 1  5       5
5 2 2 NA      NA
6 2 3 NA      NA
7 3 1  5       5
8 3 2 NA      NA
9 3 3 NA      NA
```

As one can see, only the first 3 rows were successfully filled in by mutate. It is likely that the `ifelse` function is the issue, but I can't see why : (

What is weird is that, if the `imputed` dataframe has 4 rows, like this:

```
imputed = data.frame(g=c(1,2,3,4),
                     v=c(5,10,15,20))
```

then the `df` dataframe was filled up properly:

```
  d g  v imputed
1 1 1  5       5
2 1 2 NA      10
3 1 3 NA      15
4 2 1  5       5
5 2 2 NA      10
6 2 3 NA      15
7 3 1  5       5
8 3 2 NA      10
9 3 3 NA      15
```

but R gave me a warning saying:

```
Warning message:
In imputed$g == p :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `getImputed` function. The `mutate` function does not iterate over rows. It passes columns as a vectors to functions so each function is basically called one. Your `getInputed` function works if you pass a single value, but not so great with a vector

```
getImputed(1)
# [1] 5

getImputed(c(1,2))
# [1] 5 10
# Warning message:
# In imputed$g == p :
#   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

A better way to write the function would be

```
getImputed2 <- function(p){
  imputed$v[match(p, imputed$g)]
}
```

This will properly handle a vector of values

```
mutate(df,imputed=ifelse(is.na(v),getImputed2(g),v))
#   d g  v imputed
# 1 1 1  5       5
# 2 1 2 NA      10
# 3 1 3 NA      15
# 4 2 1  5       5
# 5 2 2 NA      10
# 6 2 3 NA      15
# 7 3 1  5       5
# 8 3 2 NA      10
# 9 3 3 NA      15
```

You might also consider joining and replacing

```
mutate(join(df, setNames(imputed, c("g","v2")), by=c(g="g")), 
    v=ifelse(is.na(v), v2, v), v2=NULL)
```